# Pytest - yield inside for works only the first way around

Tags: python, pytest, yield

I'm trying to make the same tests run in different browsers. Everything works perfectly for each browser individually(["Chrome"] or ["Firefox"]), but if the supportedBrowsers array receives two elements, in the second iteration the yield simply won't do anything, the execution won't go to the tests and neither to the rest of the fixture, the browser stands there opened. What am I missing?

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def driver():
    url = "http://localhost:1234/"
    supportedBrowsers = ["Chrome", "Firefox"]
    for x in supportedBrowsers:
        if x == "Firefox":
            option = webdriver.firefox.options.Options()    
            driverObj = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
        elif x == "Chrome":
            option = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
            driverObj = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        option.headless = True
        driverObj.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
        driverObj.get(url)
        yield driverObj
        driverObj.quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried `@pytest.yield_fixture` ? (https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/yieldfixture.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's how [yield fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#yield-fixtures-recommended) work in pytest. The first `yield` is equivalent to return statement allowing for easy setup/teardown. Following yields are ignored.

The easiest way I can think of to make it work is to return a factory.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def drivers():
    def inner():
        # your previous fixture body with multiple yields goes here
    return inner
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
def test_xyz(drivers):
    for driver in drivers():
        # driver is Chrome or Firefox
```

Alternatively you can try to use [parametrized fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures). This will make your fixture looks and behave like single driver but will run each test using it twice (with Chrome and Firefox drivers).

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module', browsers=["Chrome", "Firefox"])
def driver(request):
    # here goes body of your fixture without the for loop
    # request.param holds the browser value
```

Comment: I went for the parametrized fixture and it worked marvelously. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Can you mark it as accepted answer and upvote?

Answer (score -1):

As you are using yield it is necessary to explicitly call next on the function in order to advance to the next iteration of loop. Thats how yield work. Like

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def driver():
    url = "http://localhost:1234/"
    supportedBrowsers = ["Chrome", "Firefox"]
    for x in supportedBrowsers:
        if x == "Firefox":
            option = webdriver.firefox.options.Options()    
            driverObj = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
        elif x == "Chrome":
            option = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
            driverObj = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        option.headless = True
        driverObj.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
        driverObj.get(url)
        yield driverObj 
        driverObj.quit()
d=driver() 
next(d)  # this is when the function will actually goto yield and #stop there
next(d) # next iteration of loop. 
# you have call it as many times as you have browsers
```

Alternatively you can use

```
for driver in driver():
    pass # automatically call next
```

Comment: **That's _not_ how it works.** `pytest` intentionally ignores all but the first `yield` in a fixture. Your `driver` is effectively constrained to just `Chrome`. `</facepalm>`